# Passing Json to restful WCF

Tags: .net, json, web-services, wcf, rest

I'm sending (post) Json data to a wcf service.

---

```
public interface IRegisterEmployee
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddEmployee")]
        bool ProcessEmployee(Employee emps);
    }
```

---

```
   [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Emp[] emps { get; set; }

    }
```

---

```
DataContract]
    public class Emp
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string FName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string joinDate {get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Contact[] contacts {get; set; }

    }
```

---

```
DataContract]
    public class Contact
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string key { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string value {get; set; }

    }
```

---

```
public class RegisterEmployee : IRegisterEmployee
    {
        public bool ProcessEmployee(Employee emps)
        {
            //do some processing
            return true;

        }
```

When I use fiddler to send input data (json), in debug mode I see that input (emps) contains values for **Emp** (ie FName and joinDate) however the data for **Contact** (key, value) are coming in as empty though it was present in the input. Any idea why it is coming in as empty? If I test this with soap/xml, i can see all input data and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling your service?
I tried to replicate the issue locally and I was able to get some data calling the service the following way:

```
string sURL = "http://localhost:13104/RegisterEmployee.svc/AddEmployee";

        var employee = new Employee
        {
            emps = new Emp[1] { 
                new Emp { 
                    FName = "MyFName", 
                    joinDate = "12/01/2012", 
                    contacts = new WcfService1.Contact[1] 
                    { 
                        new WcfService1.Contact { key = "myKey", value="myVailue" }  
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding ();
        byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes (json);

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        wrGETURL.Method = "POST";
        wrGETURL.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
        wrGETURL.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
        Stream requestStream = wrGETURL.GetRequestStream();            
        requestStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
        requestStream.Close();


        HttpWebResponse webresponse = wrGETURL.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        // read response stream from response object
        StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
        // read string from stream data
        string strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        // close the stream object
        loResponseStream.Close();
        // close the response object
        webresponse.Close();
        // assign the final result to text box
        Response.Write(strResult);
```

Comment: Just realized that the input I was giving in fiddler was in wrong format. Your example helped me identify it. Thanks!